# Using Terraform to create an azure active directory custom domain

Tags: azure, terraform

Is it possible to terraform an azure active directory custom domain?

Searching through the docs the only thing I see is this data resource that allows me to read the currently existing ones:

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/data-sources/domains

If this is possible,links to the appropriate docs will do

Comment: Hello @kisaragi,unfortunately  it's not possible to create custom domains from terraform as only data source is available as of now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to terraform an azure active directory custom domain?

**No.**

Unfortunately, there is no support yet for custom domain creation using the `azuread` provider within Terraform.